# mat-grid-list is not showing mat-divider correctly

Tags: angular-material2

I have the following html in Angular I am using the mat-grid-list to arrange my elements, and I want to add the divider in between, the problem is the divider is always pushed to the top before any mat-grid-tile appear:

```
<mat-grid-list rowHeight="40px" cols="8">
<mat-grid-tile colspan='1'>
    <p>Edit title:</p>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile colspan='7'>
    <some-component></some-component>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<mat-grid-tile colspan='1'>
    <p>Edit title:</p>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile colspan='7'>
    <some-component></some-component>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

and it didn't also work if I put it like this:

```
<mat-grid-tile colspan='8'>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<mat-grid-tile colspan='8'>
    <mat-divider style="width: 100%;"></mat-divider>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

the `style="width: 100%;"` fixed the issue